# ASP.NET log user out from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am building a web app using ASP.NET and the security requirements are very strict; at present the app locks out if a user is idle for 2 minutes. Each page has a javascript timer registered that starts on page load and redirects them to the lockout page after 2 minutes. When the lockout page is loaded on the server it marks the user as 'locked' in the database to stop them from navigating away without unlocking. The lockout page also has a timer set for 15 minutes after which time the user should be logged out completely.

Currently I make this happen by setting the js to redirect to a logout page which logs the user out when hit, and this gets triggered after 15 minutes. But there is nothing stopping a user from refreshing the lockout page and restarting the 15 minute timer indefinitely. I want the server to also be ticking down and boot them out after the specified time. The timings don't have to match exactly: within 10 seconds of each other would be fine.

So: is there a way to do this? Ideally the lockout page would set in motion a server-side process that boots the user out after the time runs out. Not sure how to implement such a thing, if it is even possible

Comment: It looks like most of your security relies on the client. It shouldn't, as anyone can tamper with your Javascript code and prevent the two-minute timer from ticking and/or the redirect from happening in the first place.

Comment: any reasons that you are not using session of asp.net

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I completely agree; my problem is that I don't know whether/how to have the same scenario happen but from the server. Can I start a process running that will force a target browser to redirect after the 2 minute timeout? I didn't think this was possible

Comment: @FosterZ I've read a bit about sessions but don't really see how they apply to this situation exactly? Would appreciate some more info on that if possible

Comment: @Katstevens, normally you would wait for the client to make its next request, then block it when that request reaches the server. ASP.NET sessions can be used to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for persistent data storage?  A database?

I am writing a similar client side setup to alert the user they will be logged off once fifteen minutes has elapsed, if they do not click a button indicating they are still there.  It will start with two minutes to go.

This is just a convenience my manager wants.  I already have a server side check to make sure to log the user off, if they exceed the time limit.  Actually, there are two checks.

My first check is the freshness of the cookie holding the user's session token.  Its freshness is set for fifteen minutes after each server request by the user.  If the cookie is out of date, then the user is logged out.

The other is a record of the user's last server request.  If it has been longer than fifteen minutes, then the user is logged out.

If I were you, I would use the second scheme.

In my database, I would create a lockout table that among other data would have two columns indicating if the user was locked out and at what time they were locked out.  After fifteen minutes has elapsed, if the user has not done the procedure to clear the lock out, then log off the user.  If they explicitly do the procedure, clear the lock out record.  That way, just refreshing will not clear the database column holding the lock out time.  But it would allow you to check if the fifteen minutes had elapsed.

You could condense the two columns to one, if you allow the lock out activated time to be null.  But I prefer to have a column that explicitly states if a lock out is in effect.  You could also add the columns to an existing user database.